# React-Native Android | JScode Location in APK

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, react-native, reversing

I'm trying to **reverse engineering** the apk developed by using **React-Native**. I have lack of knowledge about React-Native and also Android. I don't know how the react-native work on lower level but I read that under the currently recommended bundling instruction of *JS bundle*, JS will be includes as *plaintext* can be easily extracted.

However, I used the `dex2jar` to convert as jar file and open the source code on `JD-GUI / JADX` and haven't found the `location of JScode`. 
All I want to try is add some smali code to test how it works after recompiling the apk. But I have no idea of the JScode location.

In conclusion, I want to know about the Javascript Code location in decompiled apk.

Comment: Hi, please check first whether the code obfuscation is done or not.
You can easily check if obfuscation was successful In Android Studio via APK analyzer.
if done then not possible, if not done then you can go ahead!
May this will help you.

Comment: can i get source code (JS files) from apk?

Answer (score 4):

You can found the javascript bundle using APK Analyzer, like the image below :

[image]

If you using MacOS, you can unzip the apk, with Open the terminal and type :

```
unzip app.apk
```

You can find the javascript bundle inside of the assets folder. The name of the bundle is index.android.bundle

Comment: the source code already minified inside index.android.bundle @RajeshNasit

Comment: can it be maximized? and extract as folder?

Comment: @RajeshNasit : I think react native creates a minified bundle to prevent reverse engineering, so it will be difficult and takes time to debundle

Comment: how can i look into index.android.bundle file?